# How to populate collection from multiple DataTables

Tags: vb.net, model-view-controller

I am trying to populate a collection which comprises of two models from two data-sets at a time.I am able to populate one but not able to do for the second one. My example will clarify further,

```
 'Employee Class
    Public Class Employee
      Public Property ID As Integer
      Public Property Name as String
      Public Property Details() as DetailsCol
    End Class

Sub New(ord as Datarow)
  Me.ID= ord("ID")
  Me.Name=ord("Name")
End Sub

Public Class DetailsCol
    Inherits List(Of Details)
    Sub New()

    End Sub
End Class

 'Details class
Public Class Details
  Public Property Address As String
  Public Property Salary as Double
End Class

Sub New(ord as Datarow)
  Me.Address= ord("Address")
  Me.Salary=ord("Salary")
End Sub

'Main collection where DB call need to set both the collection
Public Class EmployeeCol
    Inherits List(Of Employee)

    Sub New()

    End Sub

    Sub New(ByVal EMP_ID As Integer)
        Dim ds As DataSet = Helper.GO_GET_DisplayEmployee(EMP_ID)
        If Not IsNothing(ds) AndAlso Not IsNothing(ds.Tables) AndAlso ds.Tables.Count > 0 Then
            'Populating Employee 
            For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
                Dim empObj As Employee = New Employee(dr)
                Me.Add(empObj)
            Next

            'TO DO: Trying to populate Details model but not finding way to do
            For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(1).Rows

            Next
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Edit**

Thanks, I am trying to re-write based on suggestion. I am able to get the employee collection about for all records but users collection is coming empty.

```
Dim rtnContent As New List(Of Employee)

        Dim ds As DataSet = Helper.GO_GET_DisplayDetails(emp_id)
        If Not IsNothing(ds) AndAlso Not IsNothing(ds.Tables) AndAlso ds.Tables.Count > 0 Then
            ds.Tables(0).TableName = "employee"
            ds.Tables(1).TableName = "users"

            ds.Relations.Add(New DataRelation("griddisplay", ds.Tables("employee").Columns("emp_id"), ds.Tables("users").Columns("emp_id")))

            rtnContent = ds.GetAccessor(Of Employee)("employee")
        End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous issues with that code but, to address your specific issue, you should start by ensuring that there is a `DataRelation` in your `DataSet` between the two `DataTables`. You can then immediately get all the child rows for any parent row and the parent row for any child row. As a general example, you can create such a `DataSet` like this:

```
Dim data As New DataSet
Dim parentTable = data.Tables.Add("Parent")
Dim childTable = data.Tables.Add("Child")

With parentTable.Columns
    parentTable.PrimaryKey = {.Add("ParentId", GetType(Integer))}
    .Add("ParentName", GetType(String))
End With

With childTable.Columns
    childTable.PrimaryKey = {.Add("ChildId", GetType(Integer))}
    .Add("ParentId", GetType(Integer))
    .Add("ChildName", GetType(String))
End With

data.Relations.Add("ParentChild",
                   parentTable.Columns("ParentId"),
                   childTable.Columns("ParentId"))
```

You can then access the child rows specific to each parent row like this:

```
For Each parentRow As DataRow In parentTable.Rows
    For Each childRow As DataRow In parentRow.GetChildRows("ParentChild")
        '...
    Next
Next
```

In your case, that means that you could/should change the constructor in your `EmployeeCol` class to something like this:

```
Sub New(employeeId As Integer)
    Dim data = Helper.GO_GET_DisplayEmployee(employeeId)

    If data?.Tables.Count = 2 Then
        For Each employeeRow As DataRow In data.Tables("Employee").Rows
            Dim detailsList As New List(Of Details)

            For Each detailsRow In employeeRow.GetChildRows("EmployeeDetails")
                detailsList.Add(New Details(detailsRow))
            Next

            Me.Add(New Employee(employeeRow) With {.Details = detailsList.ToArray()})
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

EDIT:

One of the issues I was referring to earlier was the fact that you have ADO.NET code inside your model types. That's bad design but, if you're going to do it, you could do it much more cleanly like so:

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Public Class Details

    Public Property Address As String
    Public Property Salary As Decimal

    Public Sub New(row As DataRow)
        Address = row.Field(Of String)(NameOf(Address))
        Salary = row.Field(Of Decimal)(NameOf(Salary))
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class DetailsCollection
    Inherits Collection(Of Details)

    Public Sub New(table As DataTable)
        Me.New(table.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow)())
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(rows As IEnumerable(Of DataRow))
        For Each row In rows
            Items.Add(New Details(row))
        Next
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Employee

    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
    Public ReadOnly Property Details As DetailsCollection

    Public Sub New(row As DataRow)
        Id = row.Field(Of Integer)(NameOf(Id))
        Name = row.Field(Of String)(NameOf(Name))
        Details = New DetailsCollection(row.GetChildRows($"{NameOf(Employee)}{NameOf(Details)}"))
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class EmployeeCollection
    Inherits Collection(Of Employee)

    Public Sub New(employeeId As Integer)
        Me.New(Helper.GO_GET_DisplayEmployee(employeeId).Tables(NameOf(Employee)))
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(table As DataTable)
        Me.New(table.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow)())
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(rows As IEnumerable(Of DataRow))
        For Each row In rows
            Items.Add(New Employee(row))
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Lots of improvements over your code structure in there, but I'd still write my code somewhat differently if starting from scratch. One thing to note is that there is no null-checking for the `DataSet` or `DataTables`. If it was me, I would make sure that the method that gets the data always returns a `DataSet` and it always contains two `DataTables`. If there's no data in them then so be it, and you'll end up with an empty `EmployeeCollection`.